# Array list scanner loop quit functionality

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> game = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> score = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> time = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = "yes";

    {
        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter your username: ");
            name.add(scanner.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Please enter the game: ");
            game.add(scanner.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Please Enter Achievement Score: ");
            score.add(scanner.nextInt());
            System.out.println("Please Enter Playtime: ");
            time.add(scanner.nextInt());
            System.out.print("Any letter to continue alternatively type     quit to Quit.");
            answer = scanner.next();
        } while (!answer.equals("quit"));

        if (answer.equals("quit")); //want it to go back to start     another direcotry here
        else {

            System.out.println("Thanks for adding to the database.");
            for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
                System.out.print("Username:" +name.get(i)+"\n");
                System.out.print("~~~~~~~~~~~~" +"\n");
                System.out.print("Game:" +game.get(i)+"\t");
                System.out.print("Score:" +score.get(i)+"\n");
                System.out.print("Minutes played:"+time.get(i));
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem with this is that the program is not quitting upon typing Quit but it is continuing and placing two questions on one line, shown below. how can I solve this problem?

- Please enter your username: abc123
- Please enter the game:
- GTA V
- Please Enter Achievement Score:
- 1200
- Please Enter Playtime:
- 120
- Any letter to continue alternatively type quit to Quit.Quit
- Please enter your username: Please enter the game:

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are comparing upper and lower case values of quit. You need to set them to the same case type for them to be equal and quit the program.

change your check to

```
 while (!answer.toLowerCase().equals("quit"));
    if (answer.toLowerCase().equals("quit"));
```

and that will change your input to lowercase which is what your are comparing it to.

Comment: Thank you, now. When it loops round,
Please enter your username: Please enter the game: these two appear on the same line how can i stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Your quit information `System.out.print("Any letter to continue alternatively type     quit to Quit.");` says that you need to put `quit` all lowercase word to end.

Also change `answer = scanner.next();` to `answer = scanner.nextLine();`

EDIT:
As you don't have any error control you can consider this code:

```
do {
        System.out.print("Please enter your username: ");
        name.add(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the game: ");
        game.add(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please Enter Achievement Score: ");
        score.add(Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()));
        System.out.println("Please Enter Playtime: ");
        time.add(Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()));
        System.out.print("Any letter to continue alternatively type     quit to Quit.");
        answer = scanner.nextLine();
    } while (!answer.equals("quit"));
```

I changed `scanner.nextInt()` to `Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())`. Using `nextLine()` helps scanner to flush all data before your code goes to the next line.

Comment: changing to scanner.nextLine(); gives me problem in the console, all appears on one line. Please Enter Playtime: 
2
Any letter to continue alternatively type quit to quit.Add to database
Please enter your username:

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem except that you have not closed the scanner. You can run this and you can see that the scanner is closed and go to normal execution after word quit.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> game = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> score = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> time = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = "yes";

        {
            do {
                System.out.print("Please enter your username: ");
                name.add(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Please enter the game: ");
                game.add(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Please Enter Achievement Score: ");
                score.add(scanner.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Please Enter Playtime: ");            
                time.add(scanner.nextInt());
                System.out.print("Any letter to continue alternatively type     quit to Quit.");
                answer = scanner.next();
            } while (!answer.equals("quit"));
            if(answer.equals("quit")){
                System.out.println("you have just quit");
                scanner.close();
            } //want it to go back to start     another direcotry here
            else {

                System.out.println("Thanks for adding to the database.");
                for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.print("Username:" +name.get(i)+"\n");
                    System.out.print("~~~~~~~~~~~~" +"\n");
                    System.out.print("Game:" +game.get(i)+"\t");
                    System.out.print("Score:" +score.get(i)+"\n");
                    System.out.print("Minutes played:"+time.get(i));
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }

            System.out.print("You are done with scanner");

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your program and it does quit if you type "quit" (all lowercase) like your command line instruction suggest:

> System.out.print("Any letter to continue alternatively type quit to Quit.");

If you want your quit instruction to be case-insensitive you should replace this line:

```
} while (!answer.equals("quit"));
```

with this:

```
} while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));
```

I hope that helped!